# How can I create a freestyle line without a shadowcatcher affecting the line calculation?

Tags: freestyle, shadowcatcher

In the default scene with freestyle enabled and external contour selected, I get this:
[image]

If I then add a plane below the cube you get this:
[image]

Then I enable shadowcatcher on the plane, and get this:
[image]

As you can see, the plane affects the line calculation.

So then I move the plane to its own collection and use that collection to exclude the plane from the lineset calculation:
[image]

And when I render now, I get this:
[image]

So excluding the collection does remove the lines that the plane creates, however it does not allow all of the external contour lines for the cube.

The goal is to have the full contour lines for the cube, zero lines for the shadowcatcher plane, and the shadow sitting underneath - ideally without doing multiple renders and then a composite.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Maybe split into two separate view layers

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the Contour edge type instead? That accomplishes what you want in this simple scenario.

Comment: @Bloop Nah, contour edge gives too many lines, because in the actual scene there are a ton of objects. So all objects get their contours. Which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **scene line art**:

[image]

Set edge types to contour:

[image]

Hide ground plane:

[image]

Then bake line art:

[image]

Then unhide object and check that you have line art only on necessary objects.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, even contour mode still gives too much detail to the actual line work. External contour is perfect because it truly draws *just* the outline around the whole collection, rather than each individual object and individual crease.